# No .bbl file produced with biber

Tags: biblatex, biber

I followed the instructions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations/154788#154788) to try to switch from BibTeX to Biber and biblatex. I haven't changed my `.bib` which worked fine with BibTeX, but I removed `\usepackage{cite}` and added

```
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
```

to my preamble and changed

```
\bibliography{mybib.bib}{}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

to

```
\printbibliography
```

I compile with PdfLaTeX+Biblatex+PdfLaTeX x 2 in Texmaker (PdfLaTeX = `"pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex --shell-escape`, Biblatex = biber)

I get the error:

```
Process started

Usage: biber [options] file[.bcf]
biber [options] --tool <datasource>
Creates "file.bbl" using control file "file.bcf" (".bcf" extension is optional).
Normally use with biblatex requires no options
as they are all set in biblatex and passed via the ".bcf" file
In "tool" mode (see B<--tool> option),
takes a datasource (defaults to "bibtex" datasource)
and outputs a copy of the datasource
with any command-line or config file options applied.
Please run "biber --help" for option details

Process exited with error(s)
```

The `.bcf` file is created but not the `.bbl`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `\bibliographystyyle` shouldn't be used with`biblatex`. The style is an option at loading time, like this: `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee]{biblatex}`. Furthermore, if I remember well, biber is the default bibliogrphy engine for biblatex, so the first option is not required in this case

Comment: Is the biber rule actually pointing to the target file, or just calling biber without argument?

Comment: The Biber log message looks as though you called Biber, but did not pass the file name to it. (Sometimes this is done by magic characters like `biber %` instead of just `biber`.)  Carefully double check that your settings are as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Comment: I don't know what the problem was but following @moewe's advice above I rechecked the settings and now it seems to work.

Comment: Alright, since the correct settings are listed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 it is probably best to mark this question as a duplicate even if the real source of the error can no longer be determined. (The log message certainly suggests wrong settings.)